# Normal and unitary Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

1. Can you help find a $2\times 2$ matrix with eigenvalues $1,-1$ that is not a normal matrix?

   I really tried to find one but the matrix I found is also normal!!
2. $A$ hermitian and $B$ unitary matrix and AB=BA
   I need to show $AB$ is normal matrix.
   Well I know that both $A,B$ are normal and that $A=A^*$ and $B=B^{-1}$

   Then $(AB)(AB)^* = (AB)(A^*B^*)$
   but now Im not sure what is ok to do for showing $AB$ is normal...

Comment: $(AB)^{\ast}=B^{\ast}A^{\ast}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for (1):  $A$ has the same eigenvalues as $S A S^{-1}$ for any invertible matrix $S$.  Try an $S$ that is not normal.

(2): No, $B^* = B^{-1}$ and $(AB)^* = B^* A^*$. But the statement is not true: if $A$ is hermitian and $B$ is unitary, $AB$ is not normal unless $A^2$ commutes with $B$.

Comment: strange that is what I need to prove...

Comment: Oh I forgot something I edited my question now...

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some other assumption, e.g. that $A$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$?

Comment: Oh, now it's easy.  In fact the product of two normal matrices that commute is normal.

Comment: Yes thank you for Question2 but still cant understand 1

Comment: You might try a lower (or upper) triangular matrix.

Comment: oh thats was so easy... thank you!